# Adding configChanges ="locale" programmatically

Tags: android, locale, preference

I use configChanges="locale" on my activities.
Without this options in `AndroidManifest.xml` in `2.x`, I am getting flickering screens.

It works in all my activities except in the preferences screen in which I have added programmatically.
I have one Preference Activity --> It works after setting configChanges="locale" to the AndroidManifest.xml.

Inside of the Preference Activity, I add programmatically a new preferencescreen.
For this new PreferenceScreen, I don't have an activity in the AndroidManifest.xml!
So I cannot add the configChanges="locale" and the screen flickers on 2.x !!

How can I add the attribute configChanges="locale" programmatically?

Comment: When do you get flickering screens?

Comment: On 2.x phones, but i solved it already! Thnaks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a solution to add `configChanges="locale"` programmatically, but i created a new Pereference Activity and added the configChanges keyword to the Manifest file.

Now it works as it should.